# how does message size effect message transfer speed in Kafka?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am developing a wrapper to transfer specific types of messages over Kafka. Incoming data has a high throughput. I am looking to minimize the delay in Kafka. what are the factors that effects delay in consuming messages? how does the size of the message affect the delay?